# Issues loading in javascript on single page website when navigating away and then returning

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, script-tag

Here is my website: https://memsmosaics.com/

I'm trying to make my website a single page website. When the website initally loads at index.html, it works as intended. At this time bottom section is loaded in nicely from gallery.html by the following function:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#js-content').load('/gallery.html');

    $('#js-navigation a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#js-content").load(e.target.href);
    })
  });
</script>
```

When I navigate to the about section, and then return back to the home section by clicking on 'memsmosaics' in the top left, the gallery section no longer works as it should. It looks like the javascript is no longer applied to do things it was doing before - like aligning the images, and filtering by 'sold' and 'for sale'.

I have tried moving the relevant script tags from index.html to gallery.html, but this hasn't solved the problem. I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your application or at least it had when I looked at it.
Your error is related to "missing require". 
I'm not sure how familiar you are with Node but this is because require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript. You need to fix this issue first.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Node. That sounds like something I need to fix, but is that potentially another issue? My reason for asking is because I'm wondering why everything would work how I want it to when I initially load the page but not when I return to it? - EDIT also I just tested removing that require line to get rid of the error, so now the error is gone, but my problem persists.

Comment: I'm curious, if you want to make a site a SPA, why not use one of the many frameworks available for such a thing?

Comment: @Pytth Because I don't know much about SPA. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Frankie SPA = Single Page Application. I am thinking you could use something like Vue, React, or Angular.

Comment: This might sound a bit contentious, but a full-on templating library is overkill for a website such as this. I'd actually go in the opposite direction and recommend that the OP use static pages rather than hashed routing to improve crawlability/SEO, while maintaining light JS for dynamic content. No sense in slapping 160kb of library onto a two page website to use 1% of its features, especially since OP would likely maintain the jQuery implements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for a popstate event after load, like this:

```
const initGallery = () => {
    if(location.hash === '#new-section' || location.path === '/') {
       $('#js-content').load('/gallery.html');

       $('#js-navigation a').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#js-content").load(e.target.href);
       })
    }
}

window.addEventListener('popstate', initGallery)

$(document).ready(initGallery);
```

That is triggered during navigation. Here's an article that provides a bit more insight: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-detect-when-the-browser-url-changes-with-vanilla-js/

**Edit with explanation**:
The problem you're running into is your handlers are being added *only* on load, so when the gallery is removed, you have detached DOM nodes hanging around, and they're never re-attached because the load event only fires on the initial page load. This creates a memory leak.

You can learn more about detached DOM nodes here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-detached-dom-elements-cause-memory-leak-in-javascript

You could update the code above to remove the click listener. I'm not too familiar with jQuery, but the docs demonstrate an `off` method, so your updated code could look like this alternatively:

```
const initGallery = () => {
    const onClick = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#js-content").load(e.target.href);
    }
    
    const btn = $('js-navigation a')

    if(location.hash === '#new-section' || location.path === '/') {
       $('#js-content').load('/gallery.html');
       
       btn.click(onClick)
       return
    }
    if(btn) {
        btn.off('click', onClick)
    }
}
```

This should work, per the definition of `popstate`:

> When the transition occurs, either due to the user triggering the browser's "Back" button or otherwise, **the popstate event is near the end of the process to transition to the new location**.